# Efficient encryption algorithm for encrypting large byte array

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption

For my recent project, so far I have been using SDES for encrypting any binary file. Undoubtedly, the algorithm is simple to implement; but at the same time it is not suitable for encrypting large files as it takes plaintext of size 1 byte as input i.e Encrypts 1 byte at a time. Any suggestions on more efficient encryption algorithm is appreciated.

---

Below is the simple implementation of SDES on image files:

- This segment of code encrypts the entire data bytes including the header. You can save the data bytes in form of ASCII or UTF-8 in a file and transmit over some insecure channel. Upon decryption and reconverting to an image file you can use [magic number programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

  ```
      Conversion.Convert cvt = new Conversion.Convert();
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the RGB/GRAY/BINARY image path: ");
      string path = Console.ReadLine();
      byte []arrayPT = Conversion.Convert.ImageToBinary(path); // Get the binary data from the image
      byte []arrayCT = new byte[arrayPT.Length];
      int i = 0;
      foreach (byte element in arrayPT)
      {
          arrayCT[i] = ob.Encrypt(element);
          Console.Write("{0}", arrayCT[i]); //Convert the contents of arrayCT[] into char and save into a file
          i++;
      }
  ```
- Use this approach to encrypt only the color information i.e. pixel values.

  ```
      SDES ob = new SDES(key);
      Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imgpath);
      Color pixelColor, pixels;
      //byte[] buff = new byte[3 * img.Height * img.Width];
      for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
          {
              pixels = img.GetPixel(i, j);
              pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(ob.Encrypt(pixels.R), ob.Encrypt(pixels.G), ob.Encrypt(pixels.B));
              img.SetPixel(i, j, pixelColor);
          }
      }
      img.Save(newEncryptedImg);
  ```

Comment: Isn't this what the classes in [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx) are for? Also, the approach to encrypt only the pixel values is slow because `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` are slow. You're better off looking into using [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the raw image bytes.

Comment: What do you mean with efficient, is it the speed or the strength of the encryption?

Comment: @Petoj balance between both will be good.

Comment: @pk1772: Have you heard of AES? It's quite a common cipher...

Comment: @NiklasB.- too many rounds! But I think the modified version will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the C# integrated cryptography functions? They are found in `System.Security.Cryptography`. There is a `CryptoStream` that seems to allow `Stream` based cryptographic transformations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream(v=vs.110).aspx

Those classes go back to the OS integraed cryptography packet which IIRC is pretty good.

Comment: Actually only the classes that end in "[CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)" go back to the OS integrated cryptography packet, the ones that end in "[Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)" use a fully .NET based implementation. That is why they have [abstract base classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx) that both implementations inherit from, you can use that without worrying which is used.

Comment: Also `CryptoStream` has no implementation itself, it is just a (very useful) wrapper around a [`ICryptoTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.aspx), this lets you use any class derived from [`SymmetricAlgorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) as the actual algorithm.